# Weird rendering in "Fetch as Google"

Tags: bots, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

I am getting this when I use Fetch as Google.
I have tried setting width, height in pixels for the images but it does not change.

I know that there are no clear cut answers but if you had faced this kind of issue kindly give me a clue to try out.

Thank You

[image]